# Calling a modal window from within a custom UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, model-view-controller

I have a UITableView and inside it I create a custom UITableViewCell in the follwoing way:

```
ItemCellController *cell = (ItemCellController *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ContentListsCellIdentifier];
...
cell = [[[ItemCellController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:ContentListsCellIdentifier] autorelease];
```

I do this to can get touchesBegan and touchesEnded events (so that I can implement a long touch).  Using NSLog I can see that the longTouch is called properly from within the touchesBegan method using the following code:

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(longTouch:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

The problem is that I am not able to call a modal window from within the longTouch method.

I tried the following, but I get an NSInvalidArgumentException -[ItemCellController navigationController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance error.

```
AddItemController *addView = [[AddItemController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AddItemView" bundle:nil];  

UINavigationController *controller = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:addView];
controller.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
[[self navigationController] presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
[controller release];
```

So the question is, how can I call up a modal window from within a custom UITableViewCell.

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `navigationController` property exists for `UIViewController`s, but `UITableViewCell` (which I guess `ItemCellController` is a subclass of) is not a `UIViewController`, so it doesn't have that property by default.

There are a few appraoches:

(1) Add a `UIViewController*` property (maybe call it `controller`) to your custom cell type, and pass in a pointer to your controller with your init method (say, `initWithController:`).  Then in your cell, you can just execute:

```
UINavigationController* navController = [ /* alloc and init it */ ]
[self.controller presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
```

(2) Your app delegate object could have a controller property that you can access from anywhere in your code.  Then you could do something like this:

```
MyAppDelegate* myAppDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[myAppDelegate.controller presentModalViewController:navController
                                            animated:YES];
```

(3) This one is less direct but more flexible.  You could set up your root controller (the one you want to do the presenting of the modal view) to listen for a certain notification, and post that notification from within your table cells.

Sample listen code, called from within your root controller:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(showModal:)
                                             name:@"show modal"
                                           object:nil];
```

Sample post code, called from within a table cell:

```
NSDictionary* userInfo = [ /* store a handle to your modal controller */ ];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"show modal"
                                                    object:self
                                                  userInfo:userInfo];
```

And the `showModal:` method of your root controller would use the `userInfo` included in the `NSNotification` to figure out which view controller to present modally.  That's more work, but it would automatically allow any of your code anywhere to present a modal view, without giving them full access to a root controller pointer.

Comment: Wow. The notification method is great! It really cleans things up a lot.  
Thanks.

Comment: +1 Nice answer, although I'd like to point out that Notification Center for an iPhone app is a bit overkill, since the app's only really listening to itself. [Nice write-up here.](http://blog.shinetech.com/2011/06/14/delegation-notification-and-observation/)

Answer (score 0):

It does not look like you set the cells navigation controller anywhere, it seems that it does not like [[self navigationController] presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES]; that line, check the nagivationController property on that "self" object